# IPython parallel %px works but not sync_imports (engine pythonpath issue)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, trackpy

When I write

```
%px import trackpy as tp
```

and then I use map_async with a function using the `tp` module, it just works as expected.

If I wrote intead:

```
with client[:].sync_imports():
     import trackpy as tp
```

I got a error `"NameError: name 'tp' is not defined"`.

More exactly, with the following:

```
amr = view.map_async(function_using_tp, anArray)
amr.wait_interactive()
```

the "wait_interactive" is showing a "ipython wait line" as expected, but when I tried to access the first element of the result (amr[0]) I get the error ('tp' is not defined)

I guess it is linked to the fact my IPython is working on a new Python installation, and my system PYTHONPATH still points to an older Python installation.

I have three basic questions:

- how can I "debug" the import? (I don't get any feedback if the import worked on each engine or not.)
- how can I change the PYTHONPATH for engines? (I read about a ipengine_config.py but I have none on my computer)
- How can I accomplish the same thing as the `%px` IPython magic, since I'd like to be able to execute this outside of IPython? (e.g., as a DOS command: "ipython myScript.ipy")

Comment: If you don't have an ipengine_config, file, you can create your own. The other two questions seem like they are orthogonal to eachother and should be in separate questions.